# Make sqlite table column an array of rows from another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, database-design, database-schema

I'm creating a data model of college students. One of the attributes I would like to use to describe students is their class schedule.

I have a courses table that stores data of all available courses at the university. I would like to make a schedule table with a one to many relationship with students (each student has a schedule but each schedule may have more than one student if multiple students have the same schedule).

The problem I'm having is describing the courses in the schedule. One of the columns in the schedules table would have to be an array of course ids, and there is no fixed number of courses a student could take (a full time student can take anywhere from 4 to 6 courses or maybe even more if they get permission from the Dean of their college).

Is it possible to make one of the columns in a table an array of type [other table]?

Comment: Do you really need this info your database? To get all rows of a specific table you could do: `Table.all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I got this straight.
You have this:

```
    class Course
    end

    class Student
      belongs_to :schedule
    end

    class Schedule
      has_many :students
    end
```

And you want to do this:

```
    class Course
      has_and_belongs_to_many :schedules
    end

    class Student
      belongs_to :schedule
    end

    class Schedule
      has_many :students
      has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
    end
```

Is that right?

Comment: No it's not right but the solution is in your answer I haven't looked at how I would do it in Rails I was just drawing a diagram, so I wasn't thinking about Rails relationships. By mistake I didn't put all the details of the database in the question which is why you didn't know exactly what to answer. But thank you.

Comment: @Hugo Feel free to edit your question if this answer didn't completely satisfy  you. See ya